In the Hush Money case, why was Trump not charged with the "other" crimes?
In New York law, falsifying business records (which Trump was charged with) is only a misdemeanor. However, if the falsification was done with intent to help commit or conceal a crime, then it is elevated to a felony. Famously, the prosecution provided the jurors three candidate crimes, and told them they need not agree which they felt Trump was guilty of, just so long as they all felt there was at least one. These three "other" crimes were:

violation of federal campaign finance limits
violation of state tax laws regarding the reimbursement.
violation of state election laws by unlawfully influencing the 2016 election

My understanding is that in situations where the misdemeanor of falsifying business records is upgraded to a felony, then the defendant is charged with both - the falsification of the records, and the crime it helped.
Note, in order for the misdemeanor to be upgraded to a felony, the prosecution merely needs to prove the defendant intended to commit a crime - not that they did, or it could even be proven that they did. That is not my question. My question is why, in this specific case, did the prosecution not charge any of those three crimes? Since it certainly is the case that Trump did commit them (in the argument of the prosecution), and that the prosecution was not lacking evidence of the crimes.
A bonus to answers that provide legal precedence around the topic.

Does this answer your question? Why did the prosecution not charge?

@Trish There is a key difference between that question and this one. Your proposed duplicate is a generic "Why did the prosecutor not file charges in ?" In this case, the question is a more relevant one: why were charges filed that declined to specify what the underlying crime was?"

@Machavity unless you are the prosecutor, or they gave an interview to the reasons, the question would be opinion based.

As noted in other answers, we cannot read the mind of the prosecutor, so we cannot know the exact reasons the other crimes were not charged. That said, the decision to not charge these crimes is striking, and there are some key factors that stand out as likely influencing the decision:
1. violation of federal campaign finance limits
This is a federal law, not a state law, hence the New York prosecutor could not charge it.
2. violation of state tax laws regarding the reimbursement.
The taxes were actually overpaid, because Trump reimbursed Cohen more than the hush money payment that was given to Stormy Daniels (described in this article). While Bragg argued that New York law does not require financial injury to the state for the act to be criminal, and Judge Merchan accepted that argument, it likely would have been a tough sell to the jury and bad optics to the press.
3. violation of state election laws by unlawfully influencing the 2016 election
In my view, this one is the most speculative. This is what I consider relevant:
The law in question here is SECTION 17-152 and is only a misdemeanor, stated below (emphasis mine):

§ 17-152. Conspiracy to promote or prevent election. Any two or more
persons who conspire to promote or prevent the election of any person
to a public office by unlawful means and which conspiracy is acted
upon by one or more of the parties thereto, shall be guilty of a
misdemeanor.

Prosecutors have finite resources and tend to focus on the most critical sections of a case. And since the prosecution's ultimate goal was to convict Trump of a felony, it seems reasonable that they would conserve resources rather than attempt to charge Trump with what would, at best, result in just another misdemeanor.
Other answers allude to an expired statute of limitations. This is complicated by New York pausing the limit during covid, as well as for days when the defendant is out of state (which in Trump's case is significant). It's possible the prosecution wanted to avoid such discussion (note that the limitations for a felony is 5 years, and a misdemeanor is only 2 years). (source here).
Lastly, the original question claims that the prosecution was "not lacking evidence" for all three crimes. This is maybe true for the first two crimes, but Section 17-152 is based on a "conspiracy" to influence the election; while not impossible to prove, it would not have been a slam dunk of a case as the original question insinuates.

Maybe they didn’t happen
The charge that was brought only requires proof that the falsification was done with the intention of concealing other crimes - it is not required to prove that those crimes ever happened. Indeed, a person could alter the records with the plan to conceal another crime that they believe happened and they would be guilty even if the acts they sought to conceal were not actually crimes at all.
Maybe they can’t be proved
Maybe the prosecution believes they happened but have insufficient evidence to prove it. So, you can’t get Capone on racketeering charges, so you get him on tax evasion - the parallels are eerie.
Maybe they believe someone else committed the underlying crime
The alteration doesn’t have to be to conceal your crime, altering records to conceal anyone’s crimes creates the felony.

And since Michael Cohen has already served time for violating election laws, it's the last one that fits best.

Perhaps the OP didn't realise that the crime being hidden could be someone elses.

At least as I read it, the wording "...if the acts they sought to conceal were not actually crimes at all" suggests "...if the none of acts they sought to conceal--even if committed--would have been crimes at all", and I don't think prosecution would be valid in the latter case.  If they sought to conceal multiple acts, only some of which were illegal, the fact that the only acts that were performed were legal wouldn't be a defence, but I think a prosecution would require that at least some of the acts they sought to conceal would have been illegal if committed.

Well #1 is not a state crime so this prosecution couldn’t include it. The statue of limitations could be an issue but I think proving all the elements of either of the either of the #2 and #3 crimes is harder than establishing the intent to commit at least one of the three crimes.
And prosecutorial discretion used to keep the case manageable.
I don’t understand why you think #3 is intertwined with the others.

Regarding #3 being intertwined, it was the argument Bragg himself made. Also, see here for more explanation: https://www.lawfaremedia.org/article/charting-the-legal-theory-behind-people-v.-trump

And regarding #2, I find it hard to believe it is easier to prove intent than the crime itself. How can they prove Trump "intended" to evade taxes, but not prove that he actually did evade taxes? That doesn't make any sense. (Gave an upvote since you answered #1 satisfactorily, but not the check-mark because I still don't know #2 or #3).

I intended to commit burglary as evidenced by my breaking and entering and having a large sack to carry the loot but I was scared off by the alarm so I intended but did not commit burglary.

That hypothetical situation makes sense to me. But in this case, Trump DID misstate the taxes. So, the analogy doesn't hold - the burglary was committed, and there is ample evidence of it, right?

@Jen "Not every crime is prosecuted" is not satisfactory. It make sense in isolation, but not in a case where the defendant is already facing charges, and the "other" crimes in question are extremely relevant to the case.
That's also why I'm curious if there is any precedent to this - a prosecutor saying someone "intended" to commit a crime, that they did in fact commit the crime (as Bragg said), and yet not charging the crime despite lacking no evidence.

@Jen Is there a policy that says I should ask only one question? (https://law.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) I've seen many questions on this site that have a few questions in them. Regardless, I edited the answer to reduce the number of questions.
And "prosecutorial discretion" just answers the question by restating it. "Why didn't the prosecution charge the crime?" "Because they chose not to". (Not to mention it is the wrong answer for item #1, and possibly the other two as well).

@ineedahero your last statement is true 99% of the time. Unless the prosecution wants to charge, they don't have to in most cases. If they don't have enough to convict or believe it would be violate some guideline (e.g. possession of a tiny amount of drugs), they can just deny to charge, and nobody can review that decision.
